# How to implement lookahead in Ragel

Tags: c, ragel

I have two states; one is a specific instance of the other, more general, state. 
I believe that the right way to avoid entering both states simultaneously is to implement lookahead with k>1, but I can't find any examples of how to do this.

The Ragle user's guide says:

> In both the use of fhold and fexec the user must be cautious of combining the resulting machine with another in such a way that the transition on which the current position is adjusted is not combined with a transition from the other machine.

I'm not entirely sure what this means, except perhaps "don't try to read past the end of the current expression".

My machine looks like this:

```
seglen16 = any{2} >{ swab(p, &len, 2); len = len - 2; };            
action check {len--}
buffer = (any when check)* %when !check @{ printf("[%d]:%d\n", len, *p); };

# JPEG Markers
mk_app0 = 0xFF 0xE0; 
mk_appx = 0xFF (0xE0..0xEF);
marker = 0xFF ^0x00;
nonmarker = !marker - zlen;

# JPEG APP Segments
seg_app0_jfif = mk_app0 seglen16 "JFIF" 0x00 buffer @{ printf("jfif app0\n"); };
seg_appx_unk = mk_appx nonmarker* @{ printf("unknown app content\n"); };
seg_app = (seg_app0_jfif | seg_app1_exif | seg_appx_unk);

# Main Machine  
expr = (mk_soi @lerr(bad) nonmarker* seg_app* nonmarker* mk_eoi);
```

I want to tokenize a JPEG header, skipping unknown segments and handling well-known segments like JFIF. The JPEG application segment app0 starts with `0xFFE0`. If app0 contains JFIF data, the app0 marker will be followed by a two-byte length and the string "`JFIF\0`". This means I need 7 bytes of lookahead when identifying application segments.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to tokenize a JPEG header, skipping unknown segments and handling well-known segments like JFIF. The JPEG application segment app0 starts with 0xFFE0. If app0 contains JFIF data, the app0 marker will be followed by a two-byte length and the string "JFIF\0".

All right.

> This means I need 7 bytes of lookahead when identifying application segments.

Why? You can make the "unknown" pattern apply to all segments *except* the ones that are known using the general pattern:

```
seg_app0_jfif = mk_app0 seglen16 "JFIF" 0x00 buffer @{ printf("jfif app0\n"); };
known_segment = (seg_app0_jfif | seg_app1_exif);
unknown_segment = ((mk_appx nonmarker*) - known_segment) @{ printf("unknown app content\n"); };
seg_app = (known_segment | unknown_segment);
```

Doing it this way doesn't require lookahead. Ragel generates the appropriate states and transitions, handling both patterns simultaneously until enough of the input has been processed to disambiguate them. The finishing action on `unknown_segment` will occur only if it is not a `known_segment`, which seems like behavior you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Using lookahead makes the entering transitions unambiguous. This will produce a simpler machine and make the actual pattern handling actions a great deal easier to implement.